# Laravel Eloquent raw query without "FROM" parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I need to perform the following SQL query through Laravel Eloquent:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY field_1, field_2
) AS total
```

I wouldn't have a problem if I was able to do it using the `DB::` class, but I'm forced to use the Eloquent class:

```
Customers::select(DB::raw($sql))->first()->total;
```

This piece of code returns the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY field_1, field_2
) AS total FROM customers
```

And I'd like to get rid of "FROM customers".

Comment: You cannot use "only Eloquent" to do that. Eloquent is an ORM. It maps a table. Your query has no table on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no point in using Eloquent for this.

```php
Customers::selectRaw('count(*)')->fromSub(function ($subquery) {
    $subquery->selectRaw('count(*)')
    ->from('table')
    ->groupBy(['field1','field2']);
}, 'total')
->get();
```

Running this in the console gives the following result:

```
--> use App\User; 
User::selectRaw('count(*)')->fromSub(function ($subquery) {
    $subquery->selectRaw('count(*)')
    ->from('table')
    ->groupBy(['field1','field2']);
}, 'total')
->toSql();

=> "select count(*) from (select count(*) from `table` group by `field1`, `field
2`) as `total`"
```

You'll notice I used my own model. This is what I meant by there being no point in using eloquent. From the moment you call `from()` or any of its variations (`fromSub` in this case), you're deferring to the query builder. And in this case you're not even calling the model's table.

Answer (score 1):

you can use subqueries in Eloquent for example:

```
DB::select(function ($query) {
    $query->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS total')
        ->from('table')
        ->groupBy('field_1');
        ->groupBy('field_2');
}, 'table')->count('total');
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I cannot use the `DB::select()` class.